# Convert String to Map in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below data in csv file with delimeter `|`, I want to convert string to Map for `PersonalInfo` column data so that I can extract required information.

I try to convert below csv to parquet format with `String` to `Map` using Cast I got datatype mismatch error.

Below is data for your ref. Your help is much appreciated.

```
Empcode EmpName PersonalInfo
1       abc     """email"":""abc@gmail.com"",""Location"":""India"",""Gender"":""Male"""
2       xyz     """email"":""xyz@gmail.com"",""Location"":""US"""
3       pqr     """email"":""abc@gmail.com"",""Gender"":""Female"",""Location"":""Europe"",""Mobile"":""1234"""
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way is to use [`str_to_map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#str_to_map) function after you get rid of the double quotes from `PersonalInfo` column:

```scala
val df1 = df.withColumn(
  "PersonalInfo",
  expr("str_to_map(regexp_replace(PersonalInfo, '\"', ''))")
)

df1.show(false)

//+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|Empcode|EmpName|PersonalInfo                                                                  |
//+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|1      |abc    |{email -> abc@gmail.com, Location -> India, Gender -> Male}                   |
//|2      |xyz    |{email -> xyz@gmail.com, Location -> US}                                      |
//|3      |pqr    |{email -> abc@gmail.com, Gender -> Female, Location -> Europe, Mobile -> 1234}|
//+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a map from `PersonalInfo` column, from Spark 3.0 you can proceed as follows:

- Split your string according to `"",""` using `split` function
- For each element of your obtained string array, create sub-arrays according to `"":""` using `split` function
- Remove all `""` from elements of sub-arrays using `regexp_replace` function
- Build map entries using `struct` function
- Use `map_from_entries` to build map from your array of entries

Complete code is as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, map_from_entries, regexp_replace, split, struct, transform}

val result = data.withColumn("PersonalInfo",
  map_from_entries(
    transform(
      split(col("PersonalInfo"), "\"\",\"\""),
      item => struct(
        regexp_replace(split(item, "\"\":\"\"")(0), "\"\"", ""),
        regexp_replace(split(item, "\"\":\"\"")(1), "\"\"", "")
      )
    )
  )
)
```

With the following `input_dataframe`:

```
+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Empcode|EmpName|PersonalInfo                                                                                 |
+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |abc    |""email"":""abc@gmail.com"",""Location"":""India"",""Gender"":""Male""                       |
|2      |xyz    |""email"":""xyz@gmail.com"",""Location"":""US""                                              |
|3      |pqr    |""email"":""abc@gmail.com"",""Gender"":""Female"",""Location"":""Europe"",""Mobile"":""1234""|
+-------+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You get the following `result` dataframe:

```
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Empcode|EmpName|PersonalInfo                                                                  |
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1      |abc    |{email -> abc@gmail.com, Location -> India, Gender -> Male}                   |
|2      |xyz    |{email -> xyz@gmail.com, Location -> US}                                      |
|3      |pqr    |{email -> abc@gmail.com, Gender -> Female, Location -> Europe, Mobile -> 1234}|
+-------+-------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```